# Store in a variable in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set I18n.t to a variable then call this variable inside my class. But I am getting TypeError: undefined is not an object.

```
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';
let tt = I18n.t;

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
         <Text>{tt('greeting')}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be useful check it out:

```
var tt = (translation) => I18n.t(translation);


<Text>{tt('greeting')}</Text>
```

Comment: I know about it. My question is if I can assign I18n.t to some variable and call it where I need

Comment: please check the edited answer for storing it in a variable

Comment: Yes that worked. but can yo u add some explanation to it